# PyCharmからpipのライブラリをインストールする方法

Tags: python

コマンドラインから`pip install`を実行するのではなく、PyCharm から pip のライブラリをインストールする方法はありますか？

Comment: 御利用中の OS、Python や PyCharm のバージョン等を記載したほうが正確な回答をもらえると思います。

Comment: 質問が漠然としすぎていてます。何に困っているかを明記してください。例えばライブラリをインストールする際にエラーが出ているのであれば、そのエラーを記載するなどです。また、Shironeさんのコメントにあるように補足情報の記載もお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

PyCharmのPreferencesから「Project: プロジェクト名」>「Project Interpreter」とすすむとそのプロジェクトで指定されているInterpreterとそこにインストールされているライブラリの一覧が表示されます．
ライブラリ一覧の左下に「+」ボタンがあるので、それをクリックすると「Available Packages」というポップアップウィンドウが表示されます．そこではライブラリをインクリメンタルに検索できるのでインストールしたいライブラリを選択後、「Install Packages」ボタンを入力すればインストールできます。

Comment: 上記正統派の他、requirements.txtをプロジェクトルートに置くと勝手にpip install -rだと解釈して"XXXがはいっていないけど入れる？"と聞いてくるのでYesと答えれば入ります。個人的にはrequirements.txtの更新忘れが起きにくいのでこちらのほうがオススメ。